Почему нельзя чистить таймер через присвоение переменной таймера значения null?
У меня есть код функции debounce
function debounce(func, time) {
let timer;
    return function () {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(func, time);
    };
}

Почему очищать таймер нужно именно так, а не, допустим, просто присвоением timer значения null?

Ну видимо под капотом там сложная логика по остановке всех процессов. Это примерно как "выключить комп" одной кнопкой, но по факту происходит сохранение данных, очистка памяти, закрытие программ, замыкание.размыкание цепей, и пр..... И простое выкавыривание кнопки из ПК не даст того же эффекта

потому что timer всего лишь хранит номер задания. setInterval это апи среды выполнения кода(браузер/нода), как и clearInterval. Т.е. clearInterval скажет среде выполнения кода(браузер/нода/иное), что надо остановить таймер с номером таким то.

Если все это сложно, то есть простой ответ: Так придумали и так исторически сложилось, что это делается именно так. А почему именно так когда то сделали ¯\(ツ)/¯

Присвоив переменной null вы только разорвёте связь этой переменной с таймером. Но с самим таймером при этом ничего не произойдёт. Если в js есть garbage collector, то может быть таймер будет утилизирован через какое-то время, но опять же это лотерея какая-то.

@CrazyElf номер таймера это не ссылка на таймер, а просто номер. Таймер(интервал) сам живет в среде выполнения(браузер/нода). Удалив номер, просто удаляем номер, а таймер как жил, так и будет жить, запуская указанный js код... garbage есть в js, но до таймера не доберется, т.к. он раз живет в браузере/ноде, два, может так   надо крутить его вечно. Поэтому clearInterval - это апи от среды выполнения для остановки таймер, куда передается его номер.

@SwaD А, понятно. Но в главном то я прав ))

@SwaD, реализация clearInterval и setInterval могут различаться в зависимости от среды выполнение. Не везде возвращаемое значение setInterval это просто число.

Очистка таймера с помощью clearTimeout(timer) нужна для того, чтобы отменить уже запланированный вызов переданной функции func, если он существует. Если бы вместо этого вы присваивали timer значение null, это только удалило бы ссылку на текущий таймер, но не остановило бы запланированное выполнение функции func.
Каждый вызов setTimeout возвращает уникальный идентификатор таймера, который используется clearTimeout для определения конкретного таймера, который должен быть отменён. Если новый вызов функции происходит до того, как таймер истёк и функция func была выполнена, clearTimeout гарантирует, что предыдущее выполнение будет отменено, и создастся новый таймер для следующего выполнения func. Это обеспечивает, что функция будет вызвана только один раз, через заданный интервал времени после последнего вызова.
Присвоение timer значения null без предварительной очистки существующего таймера не предотвратит возможного уже запланированного выполнения функции func.

Вот это хорошее объяснение, правильное.

@CrazyElf, а по-моему этот ответ на вопрос вообще не отвечает. Вопрос звучит "Почему очищать таймер нужно именно так", а вовсе не "как устроена приведённая и функция".


А ты видел, что в переменной? Там число.
var x = 100
x = null // Очистили таймер 100?


Даже если бы был объект, в js, в отличие от си++, нет определённого времени жизни объектов, а значит, то, что ссылки на некий объект больше не существуют, не означает, что сборщик мусора его скоро соберёт. А даже если соберёт, деструктора всё равно нет (ладно-ладно, теперь через WeakRef можно привязать, но ведь не было же), поэтому код по очистке не выполнить.

Даже если бы это был си++ и уничтожение таймера можно было реализовать через уничтожение ссылки на объект, то вылез бы побочный эффект - ты обязан держать объект до тех пор, пока не выполнится таймер:
setTimeout(() => {
  // Никогда не произойдёт
  // Поскольку объект не сохранили и он умер сразу же после вызова
  // и отменил таймер
  console.log("Hi")
}, 100)




Зачем вы вводите людей в заблуждение? В третьем пункте - в консоли без помех печатается "Hi", даже если таймер поставить значительно дольше.

@black1277, там же сказано "если бы ... уничтожение таймера можно было реализовать через уничтожение ссылки на объект" ;)

Потому что timer, в вашем случае, это не сам таймер, а лишь его идентификатор. Т.е. просто присвоением timer значения null вы потеряете идентификатор вашего таймера и больше не сможете с этим таймером ничего сделать. А сам таймер продолжит работать где-то в браузере.
И даже если бы timer содержал ссылку на сам объект таймера, просто присвоением timer значения null вы потеряли бы эту ссылку. А сам таймер продолжил бы работать где-то в браузере.
